# Update Query with an Aggregate function on one table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate

I know this question may been answered, but many of the examples I run across involve using INNER JOIN to transfer data from one table to another and my situation is a little different.

Basically what I'm trying to do is turn this SELECT statement into a Update statement.

```
SELECT 
    SR, 100. * Cast(Round(AVG(Three_1 + Three_2 + Three_3 + Three_4 + Three_5 + Three_6 + Three_7 + Five_1 + Six_1 + Six_3) / 38,0) as int)
FROM 
    MainDB 
WHERE 
    Ctype = 'Call'
GROUP BY 
    SR
```

I was able to successfully calculate the the percentage of some my columns and then i wanted to update the columns with that information. My first attempt was this

```
UPDATE QAMainDB 
SET TCX_score = 100. * avg(three_1 + Three_2 + Three_3 + Three_4 + Three_5 + Three_6 + Three_7 + Five_1 + Six_1 + Six_3) / 38
```

I got the error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

After doing more trail and error I tried this approach to Declare a variable from a previous example on Stack.

```
Declare @Result Decimal = 0

SET @Result = 100. * Cast(round(avg(three_1 + Three_2 + Three_3 +  Three_4 + Three_5 + Three_6 + Three_7 + Five_1 + Six_1 + Six_3) / 38,0) as int)

UPDATE QAMainDB
SET TCX_score = @Result
WHERE Ctype = 'Call'
```

But it failed, I was wondering if any of you guys could help me out by leading me in the right direction. I'm pretty new to SQL so please bear with me.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

How are you matching the columns?  I am guessing that `SR` is the column used for matching between the tables:

```
WITH m as (
      SELECT SR, 100. * Cast(Round(AVG(Three_1 + Three_2 + Three_3 + Three_4 + Three_5 + Three_6 + Three_7 + Five_1 + Six_1 + Six_3) / 38,0) as int) as val
      FROM MainDB 
      WHERE Ctype = 'Call'
      GROUP BY SR
     )
Update QAMainDB
    SET TCX_score = val
    FROM QAMainDB JOIN
         m
         ON m.SR = QAMainDB.SR;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Well at first i was using the ID to match the columns but then i changed it to SR for a different reason. Anyway i tried your code and also something simular when i was trying to use a INNER JOIN technique from a previous example and i got the same error with your code to.

Comment: No column name was specified for column 2 of 'm'.

Comment: thank its worked, after running it in Management studio. I was using VS studio object explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Try change your code to this one.

```
Update QAMainDB SET  TCX_score = (select 100. * avg(three_1 + Three_2 + Three_3 + Three_4 + Three_5 + Three_6 + Three_7 + Five_1 + Six_1 + Six_3) / 38)
```

Comment: Hey bro thanks for the fast response i tried you solution as well and got the same error i did before.
An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Comment: update m_produk set harga = (select 100*avg(old.harga+200)/5) where id =  1

Comment: sorry i  mean, update m_produk set harga = (select 100*avg(harga+200)/5) where id =  1 << this code

Comment: thank its worked, after running it in Management studio. I was using VS studio object explorer.